# How to get the first and the last parts of string separated by a space

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, split

If I have a name consists of more than one part separated by a space, and I want to get:

```
the first name + " " + the last name.
```

Is there any way to do that.

- No rules except that the names separated by a space.
- There are any number of parts.

Example:

```
john depp lennon
```

To:

```
john lennon
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string sString = "john depp lennon";
string[] sArray = sString.Split(' ');

string sStartEnd = sArray[0] + " " + sArray[sArray.Count()-1]; // "john lennon"
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to return if there is just one name.. like 'Bono.. this would retrun 'Bono Bono'.. also, I'd just use sArray.Length-1

Comment: the only problem with composite names !!!! .it takes the last part of them as the last name.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned LINQ in the tags, I'll get you that, skipping validation for entering one part (only "Johm") or entering nothing at all, that will be:

Ensure you have:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then:

```
var nameParts = name.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", nameParts.First(), nameParts.Last());
```

Thise will do the job for the happy path

---

If we want to check for edge cases, we can add extra checks:

```
static string GetName(string nameEntry)
{
    // assuming .NET 4, or use string.IsNullOrEmpty(), 
    //    as we are protected later from white space-only text
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameEntry))
        return string.Empty; // Or throw error. Your choice

    var nameParts = nameEntry.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(!nameParts.Any()) return string.Empty(); // Or throw error. Your choice

    if(nameParts.Length == 1)
        return nameParts.First();

    var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", nameParts.First(), nameParts.Last());
    return fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "john depp lennon";      
string[] data = str.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Format("{0} {1}", data.First(), data.Last());
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if the string doesn't have exactly 3 parts.

Comment: @svick may be you missed he said no rules, Any way updated my answer ,  thanks :)

Comment: I think "no rules" doesn't mean "the result can be anything", but something like "the input can be anything".